# AJAX Multiple Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm not a Javascript master however I tried hard to prevent this. This script keeps randomly sending multiple posts. I couldn't manage to stabilize it. Usually works fine and sends one post per click. However sometimes it just decides that it should be posted like 5-6 times... Note that using `async: false` did not really make any difference. And it prevents me from disabling the button after the submission and its not because of "number of clicks" either. Thanks in advance!

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    var personal_text_data = document.getElementById('personal_text').value;
    var lang_option_data = document.getElementById('language_option').checked;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'send.php',
        cache: false,
        // async: false,
        data: ({
            notification_type: notification_type_data,
            customer_id: customer_id_data,
            personal_text: personal_text_data,
            language_option: lang_option_data
        }),
        success: function () {
            delete customer_id_data;
            delete personal_text_data;
            delete notification_type_data;
            delete lang_option_data;
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This code by itself doesn't seem like it would cause that problem.  Is something else invoking this multiple times?  Is the user clicking the button multiple times?  Have you been able to reliably replicate the issue at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault();` to avoid the ajax submission and normal form submit from happening. Also change the click event and make it `$('[yourForm]').submit()`.

```
$('[selectorToYourForm]').submit(function (e) {
    $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
    e.preventDefault();
    var personal_text_data = document.getElementById('personal_text').value;
    var lang_option_data = document.getElementById('language_option').checked;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'send.php',
        cache: false,
        // async: false,
        data: ({
            notification_type: notification_type_data,
            customer_id: customer_id_data,
            personal_text: personal_text_data,
            language_option: lang_option_data
        }),
        success: function () {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```